# Save pandas dataframe but conserving NA values

Tags: python, csv, pandas, nan, na

I have this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': 'cat dog cat fish dog cat cat'.split(),
               'size': list('SSMMMLL'),
               'weight': [8, 10, 11, 1, 20, 12, 12],
               'adult' : [False] * 5 + [True] * 2});
```

And I changed the weight with NA  values:

```
df['weight'] = np.nan
```

And finally I saved it

```
df.to_csv("ejemplo.csv", sep=";", decimal=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, index=False)
```

But when I read the file I have "", instead of NA 
I want to put NA instead of Nan

I want as output:

```
adult;animal;size;weight
False;"dog";"S";NA
False;"cat";"M";NA
```

Comment: pass param `na_rep` so `df.to_csv("ejemplo.csv", sep=";", decimal=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, index=False, na_rep='NA')`

Comment: yes but I want the NA without quotes

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get that specific output, you'll have to pass the quotes in explicitly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': r'"cat" "dog" "cat" "fish" "dog" "cat" "cat"'.split(),
           'size': list(r'"S" "S" "M" "M" "M" "L" "L"'.split()),
           'weight': [8, 10, 11, 1, 20, 12, 12],
           'adult' : [False] * 5 + [True] * 2}); 
df['weight'] = '%s' %('NA')
df.to_csv("ejemplo.csv", sep=';', decimal=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, index=False)
```

Comment: I want this output:
    adult;animal;size;weight
    False;"dog";"S";NA
    False;"cat";"M";NA

Answer (score 19):

If you want a string to represent `NaN` values then pass [`na_rep`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) to `to_csv`:

```
In [8]:
df.to_csv(na_rep='NA')

Out[8]:
',adult,animal,size,weight\n0,False,cat,S,NA\n1,False,dog,S,NA\n2,False,cat,M,NA\n3,False,fish,M,NA\n4,False,dog,M,NA\n5,True,cat,L,NA\n6,True,cat,L,NA\n'
```

If you want the `NA` in quotes then escape the quotes:

```
In [3]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': 'cat dog cat fish dog cat cat'.split(),
               'size': list('SSMMMLL'),
               'weight': [8, 10, 11, 1, 20, 12, 12],
               'adult' : [False] * 5 + [True] * 2})
df['weight'] = np.NaN
df.to_csv(na_rep='\'NA\'')

Out[3]:
",adult,animal,size,weight\n0,False,cat,S,'NA'\n1,False,dog,S,'NA'\n2,False,cat,M,'NA'\n3,False,fish,M,'NA'\n4,False,dog,M,'NA'\n5,True,cat,L,'NA'\n6,True,cat,L,'NA'\n"
```

**EDIT**

To get the desired output use these params:

```
In [27]:
df.to_csv(na_rep='NA', sep=';', index=False,quoting=3)
​
Out[27]:
'adult;animal;size;weight\nFalse;cat;S;NA\nFalse;dog;S;NA\nFalse;cat;M;NA\nFalse;fish;M;NA\nFalse;dog;M;NA\nTrue;cat;L;NA\nTrue;cat;L;NA\n'
```

Comment: But I want the strings with quotes (not NA)

Comment: I want this output:
    adult;animal;size;weight
    False;"dog";"S";NA
    False;"cat";"M";NA

Comment: Check my updated answer also there was nothing stopping you from just adding the additional param to see if it did what you want

Comment: still dont have what i want ... I have a R process that create this output like this ... but when I transalate my code to python, I don't have exactly the same, and I am afraid that next process won't give same results a cause of this situation. I want strings between quotes, numbers no, empty strings = "" and empty numbers = NA.

Comment: Sorry it can't be done unless you post-process the csv, I can't find any combination of params to achieve what you want

Comment: follow up to the above:  what if there are other NA-like values (nans, nones, zeroes, empty) and I want to: 1) keep NA as NA, because it stands for North America,  AND 
2) I don't want NaNs, Nones, zeroes and any other na-like values to be NA?