# Is there a way to allow NaN values to be writen to CSV from panadas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following error `builtins.AssertionError: 12 columns passed, passed data had 6 columns` The last 6 Columns datawise will vary so Im happy to have `None` in the areas the data is missing. However I cant seem to find a simple way to do this, im pretty sure there must be an option for it but I cant see it in the docs or any google searches.

Any help would be apprecaited. I would like to reiterate that I know what is causing the problem and I know data is missing from coloumns. I would like to ignore missing data and am ahppy to have None or NaN in the output csv.

Comment: Do you use `df.to_csv(file)` ?

Comment: Yes I did, have alluded to that in the question now

Comment: Can you share an example of your data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405994/save-pandas-dataframe-but-conserving-na-values    

this might help!

Comment: This is an example `('Person', 'Title', 'AnotherPerson', 'AnotherPerson2', 'AnotherPerson3', 'AnotherPerson4', 'Date', 'Group')` the `AbotherPerson` entires could to to 6 or so but may only be up to 2.

Comment: @ShrinivasDeshmukh I have tried to use `na_rep=` to no avail. I get the same error

Comment: That is an example of column headers, how do you try and pack it with data?

Comment: did you try using 'quoting' attribute? quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have fixed headers, so my solution would be to extend each row respectively:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ('Person', 'Title', 'AnotherPerson', 'AnotherPerson2', 'AnotherPerson3', 'AnotherPerson4', 'Date', 'Group')
mandatory = len(columns)

data = [[1,2,3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
data = list(map(lambda x: dict(enumerate(x)), data))

data = [[item.get(i, np.nan) for i in range(mandatory)] for item in data]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```