# I can not save N/A in pandas csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this in csv file new.csv

```
company_name,industry,job_title,state,url
N/A,Accounting,Maintenance Person,Accounting,Arizona,https://www.jobs2careers.com/results3.php?q=Accounting&l=Littlefield%2C+AZ&s=150
```

and when I try to save to item.csv it remove N/A so I got this

```
company_name,industry,job_title,state,url
,Accounting,Maintenance Person,Arizona,https://www.jobs2careers.com/results3.php?q=Accounting&l=Littlefield%2C+AZ&s=150
```

I tried encoding, but unsuccessfully

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('new.csv',encoding='utf-8')

df.to_csv('item.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save pandas dataframe but conserving NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405994/save-pandas-dataframe-but-conserving-na-values)

Comment: Try passing the argument `na_filter=False` to the `read_csv` function

Comment: na_filter=False did the job, thank you very much!